# How do you run an OR query in Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, peewee

I'd like to run a query for a user based on username or email address.

I must be missing it, but I can't find how to run an `OR` query in the peewee documentation. How do you do that?

Comment: It's **very** bad form to delete a question that somebody took the effort to answer. Please don't do that.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that someone had answered

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#filtering-records)

> If you want to express a complex query, use parentheses and python’s bitwise or and and operators:

```
>>> Tweet.select().join(User).where(
...     (User.username == 'Charlie') |
...     (User.username == 'Peewee Herman')
... )
```